# How add a non-english named file to setup project in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have build a wpf application and I want to deploy it by making Setup project.
My application contains non-english (none Unicode) named files. now on building setup it fails by throwing exception:

```
Could not find file 'D:\ ... \ایران' 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.'
```

Note that I can't rename files anyway, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio supports only single language packages. So your MSI has a predetermined language (English by default) which sets the [package code page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Any character not supported by the MSI code page will either be converted or trigger some sort of error.

So if you have file names which use characters from a non-English language, you need to [change your package code page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcx25hzz%28VS.80%29.aspx) to support those characters. This will also change your package UI language.

Another approach is to rename your files to be supported by the English code page.